# Center each child view in RecyclerView

Tags: android, layout-manager, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to create a horizontal `RecyclerView` which consists of cards. I want each card to be displayed in the center of the screen and then I can scroll horizontally.
I set the `LinearLayoutManager`to be horizontal like so :

```
linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), 
            LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
```

The xml for the fragment is as follows :

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    tools:context="com.rubberduck.pairup.fragments.FavoritesFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_favorites"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
</FrameLayout>
```

I've also set `layout_gravity` to be center in the `CardView` which is the child view for the RecyclerView but to no avail. The card is always displayed on the top left.

How can I accomplish this?

**EDIT**

CardView :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cv_pair"
    cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_shirt"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/image_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/image_height"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/tshirt" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_trouser"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/image_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/image_height"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iv_shirt"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/jeans" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: post code of your card view too

Comment: @belowporverty I've added the code for the card view.